# How to switch direction of axis in 3D scatterplot plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, axis, scatter, plotly-python

I plotted the following using plotly and got the resulting plot shown before. X is the # of hours in a day, Y is a proportion between 0-1, and Z is a categorical variable with levels {0,1,2}.

However, it's unclear why the X seems to be going the opposite direction of what we're used to with a 3D Cartesian place where it's down(-) and up(+), left(-) and right(+), and front(-) and back(+). However, X seems to decrease from front to back instead of increase. I am new to plotly and am not sure how to flip the axis so it goes from 0 to 1 instead of 1 to 0. I would greatly appreciate help on this!

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(X_combined, x='x', y='y', z='z',
          color='set', symbol='predictions', opacity=0.7)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                         line=dict(width=5,
                         color='Black')),
                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
```

[image: Plotly plot]

Answer (score 5):

For 3D plots, the options for axes are under `layout.scene`. 
The `autorange` option is therefore located under `layout.scene.xaxis.autorange` and can be modified like this:

```
fig.update_scenes(xaxis_autorange="reversed")
```

References:

- [python/3d-axes](https://plotly.com/python/3d-axes/)
- [python/layout-scene-xaxis-autorange](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis-autorange)

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://plot.ly/python/axes/#reversed-axes) should do the trick:

`fig.update_xaxes(autorange="reversed")`

Alternatively, you can reverse it with a specific range:

`fig.update_xaxes(range=[9, 3])`

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. Not sure if this is it, but maybe that only works for 2d plots and not 3d scatterplots?

Comment: @JaneSully, It should work for 3D plots: [According to this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/803#issuecomment-432797559)
What happens when you try this?

Comment: Nothing -- it doesn't give an error but doesn't do anything helpful either.

Comment: @JaneSully Make sure you have plotly version newer than 3.4.0 as per [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/803#issuecomment-432853681)

Comment: @JaneSully, Any luck?